# Moving a branch in treeview

Tags: c++, c, winapi, treeview, treeviewitem

I have stumbled upon [this](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.ole/2004-05/0049.html) suggestion that claims following:

If I move children of the node to the new node, *all their descendants* will move with them *automatically*, so there would be no need for recursive copying of nodes.

I really like this idea, but I do not believe it is possible in WinAPI, based on my reading of the documentation.

### QUESTION:

Is this information correct -> can you truly move entire branch by just changing the parent of the topmost child?

If it is, can you show me how to do that?

Comment: No it can't be done, the tree control doesn't allow you to re-parent existing items.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: thought so...